# Swift string variables localization

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, localization, xcode6

I have a big project with lots of text stored both in labels in storyboard and variables. I know how to localize text in labels, but have no idea how to localize string variables. Can you explain that or give a link to the guide. I'm using Xcode version 6.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In code, you use `NSLocalizedString()` with your base language:

```
NSLocalizedString("This is my text", comment: "Label in mainView")
```

The comment can be left empty "" but it is useful for the translator (even if this is you) to know where the string comes from.

Xcode automatically creates a file `Localizable.strings` in your project in a subfolder for the language. The file contains entries like that:

```
/* Label in mainView */
"This is my text" = "Dies ist mein Text";
```

You can translate the strings in that file with a text editor of your choice.

A better way to work with translations is to select the project target in Xcode, then choose from the menu

**Editor->Export For Localization...**

This will create a folder in a location of your choice containing a language file in xliff format, i.e. for german: `de.xliff`

`xliff` is a standardized (XML) format. It is somewhat hard to edit that file in a simple text editor. I use [iXLIFF](http://pl.appzapp.us/App/iXLIFF-944658897.html) for that. It is a very small application for the Mac and makes translations a breeze.

After translating the xliff file go to Xcode

**Editor->Import Localizations...**

and choose the xliff file. Xcode will tell you when something is missing.

Comment: I got a strange mistake after I've written this code. The text of mistake: `2015-04-06 15:37:53.763 MiniGames Ultra[57948:188222] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary on line 10. Parsing will be abandoned. Break on _CFPropertyListMissingSemicolon to debug.`

Comment: You missed the semicolon at the end of one of the lines in the strings file