# xcode: How to localize strings in code?

Tags: xcode, string, swift, localization

With localize I mean translate into different languages.
I only found Instructions for localizing the storyboard but I also have strings that I set in Code.
(I'm using Swift)

Comment: See my answer here: [Swift string variables localization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470140/swift-string-variables-localization/29470518#29470518)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short — see the [`NSLocalizedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedString) function. This is also there in Swift... its declaration looks like this:

```
func NSLocalizedString(
    key: String,
    tableName: String? = default,
    bundle: NSBundle = default,
    value: String = default,
    #comment: String) -> String
```

The third through sixth arguments have default values, so you can call it like this:

```
NSLocalizedString("foo") // -> Maybe「フー」in your Japanese strings file?
```

Or like this:

```
NSLocalizedString("foo", comment: "metasyntactic variable")
```

Or with any other combination of arguments.

Check out the [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i) in Apple's documentation.

Comment: I tried this on my project, but I can't make NSLocalize return localized strings :(